# Monomorphism that is not left-invertible, epimorphism that is not right-invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, category-theory, group-homomorphism

Exercise 0.3 (b) in *Topology: A Categorical Approach* by Bradley, Bryson and Terilla asks for an example of an epimorphism that is not right-invertible. Before I get to that, I am trying to understand the example given of a monomorphism that is not left-invertible. Below is a quote from page 14:

> For example, the map $n \mapsto 2n$ defines a left-cancellative group homomorphism $f \colon \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z$. However, there is no group homomorphism $g \colon \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ so that $gf = \text{id}_{\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z}$.

I try to explain this to myself as follows. We have a homomorphism $f$ such that $f([0]_2) = [0]_4$ and $f([1]_2) = [2]_4$. The text says on page 14 that a function is injective $\Leftrightarrow$ function is left-cancellative. Therefore, the morphism (function) $f$, clearly being injective, must be left-cancellative.

Unfortunately I cannot justify the assertion that there is no $g$ such that $gf = \text{id}_{\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z}$. Perhaps the most succinct reason why I'm struggling with the idea that $f$ is not left-invertible is that group homomorphisms are in fact functions, and the text says that a function is injective $\Leftrightarrow$ it has a left inverse.

I figure if I can't understand this example, I have no hope of giving an example of an epimorphism that is not right-invertible. I appreciate any help.

**Edit: epimorphism that is not right-invertible**

I would appreciate verification that this example is correct. Consider the group homomorphism $h \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z$ given by $z \mapsto z \mod 3$. Because this morphism (function) is surjective, it is right-cancellative, i.e. epic.

We want to show that there is no group homomorphism $g \colon \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ such that $hg = \text{id}_{\mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z}$. I was able to show in a few lines that $g$ must be the trivial homomorphism. Therefore, for example, $h \big( g ( [2]_3 ) \big) = h(0) = [0]_3 \neq [2]_3$, as desired.

Comment: Related: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81123/examples-of-categories-where-epimorphism-does-not-have-a-right-inverse-not-surj), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550789/injective-vs-monic-in-categories-where-it-makes-sense), and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76539/concrete-categories-where-epis-are-just-surjections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question asked for an epimorphism that is not right-invertible, I may as well submit an answer using the one I found. Hopefully it is correct.

Consider the group homomorphism $h \colon \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z$ given by $z \mapsto z \mod 3$. Because this morphism (function) is surjective, it is right-cancellative, i.e. epic.

We want to show that there is no group homomorphism $g \colon \mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ such that $hg = \text{id}_{\mathbb Z / 3 \mathbb Z}$. I was able to show in a few lines that $g$ must be the trivial homomorphism. Therefore, for example, $h \big( g ( [2]_3 ) \big) = h(0) = [0]_3 \neq [2]_3$, as desired.

Comment: It is indeed correct.

Answer (score 3):

Any such $g$ must take $[1]_4$ to $[0]_2$ or $[1]_2$. It therefore takes $[2]_4$ to $[0]_2$.
But $f([1]_2)=[2]_4$, so $(g\circ f)([1]_2)=g([2]_4)=[0]_2\ne[1]_2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It would appear that my confusion has to do with the fact that a function $h \colon \mathbb Z / 4 \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ can either be a homomorphism or a left inverse, but not both.